# Why don't we have zone id (like in IPv6 addresses after % character) in IPv4 addresses?

Tags: networking, ipv6, ipv4

In IPv6 addresses we can see one zone id appended with percentile % character (e.g. `fe80::1ff:fe23:4567:890a%3`) for identifying interfaces. But why don't we have them in IPv4 addresses?

Comment: Because _every_ IPv6 interface has  the same network, so you need the Zone ID to determine which interface is meant when sending to that network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But I check the ipv4 netconf, the description of  ipv4-address mentioned the zone id.
http://www.netconfcentral.org/modules/ietf-inet-types

```
  typedef ipv4-address {
  type string {
    pattern
      '(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}'
        + '([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])'
        + '(%[\p{N}\p{L}]+)?';
  }
  description
    "The ipv4-address type represents an IPv4 address in
   dotted-quad notation.  The IPv4 address may include a zone
   index, separated by a % sign.

   The zone index is used to disambiguate identical address
   values.  For link-local addresses, the zone index will
   typically be the interface index number or the name of an
   interface.  If the zone index is not present, the default
   zone of the device will be used.

   The canonical format for the zone index is the numerical
   format";
}
```